# Punctuation marks in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I'm a Java beginner and given a sentence like

```
"Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]Gar_1. 
 Se excluye arbitraje de ley y [rotura de lunas]noGar"
```

I want to identify

```
"[rotura de lunas]Gar_1" and "[rotura de lunas]noGar".
```

So, I wrote the following regex:

```
"(.\*)Gar_1 (.\*) \\1noGar".
```

This works as long as I have no punctuation marks between the string attached to `"Gar_1"` and the string attached to `"noGar"`. But as soon as I have a period (`.`), like in the sentence I wrote at the beginning, then no match is found. I've tried adding things like `"(\\pP)*"` to my regex, to try and include the possibility of punctuation marks between the two strings I want to identify, but this doesn't work, either.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

`\[.+?\]\w+`

It will non-greedily match everything between `[]`, and `\w` signifies any *word* character, so that will match the last part of the string you want to capture.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax seems to be wrong at `(.\*)`. Is it Java?
I would try using Greedy Quantifier: `"(.*?)Gar_1 (.*?) \\1noGar"`.

Read more at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures the strings you want to Groups 1 and 3:

```
(?s)((\[[^\]]*\])Gar_1).*?\2noGar
```

In the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/cN9nB1), look at Groups 1 and 3 in the right pane.

To inspect them:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?s)((\\[[^\\]]*\\])Gar_1).*?\\2noGar", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // do something with Gar_1: regexMatcher.group(1)
            System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(1));
    // do something with nogar: regexMatcher.group(3)
            System.out.println(regexMatcher.group(3));
    }
}
```

- `(?s)` enables `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines
- `((\[[^\]]*\])Gar_1)` captures the `[rotura de lunas]Gar_1` to Group 1. Inside it,
- the `(\[[^\]]*\])` matches `[rotura de lunas]` and captures it to Group 2
- `.*?` lazily eats up characters, until we can match...
- `\2noGar`, which is Group 2 followed by `noGar`, i.e. `[rotura de lunas]noGar`

**Simple Replacement**

You can add capturing parentheses around groups of interest to help you build replacement strings. For instance, this replaces `Gar1` by `noGar`

```
String subject = "[rotura de lunas]Gar_1 blah [rotura de lunas]noGar";
String replaced = subject.replaceAll("(?s)((\\[[^\\]]*\\])Gar_1)(.*?)(\\2noGar)", "$2noGar$3$4");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

See the output at the bottom of the [online demo](http://ideone.com/sPwS73).

Comment: FYI added explanation

Comment: Thanks! Your code and explanation are very clear, and it works almost perfectly. The only problem is that it replaces ALL 'Gar_1' by 'noGar', while I want to replace only those 'Gar_1' which have the same preceding group of words as a corresponding 'noGar'. Namely, if I have '[rotura de lunas]Gar_1 blabla [rotura de lunas]noGar blabla [arbitraje medico]Gar_1', I want to substitute only the 'Gar_1' corresponding to '[rotura de lunas]' by 'noGar'. In order to do this, I cannot use what you wrote above. Any suggestions?

Comment: `I want to substitute only the 'Gar_1' corresponding to '[rotura de lunas]' by 'noGar'` Yeah, that was clear, and that's exactly what my regex does, I think? :) The group of words is captured as Group 2, and before `noGar` we match that Group 2 again. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're not using any "replace" function in you example, so I added my own lines with "replaceALL" but this, together with your regex, leads to replacing ALL 'Gar_1', which is not what I want to do... :( How do I replace them selectively?

Comment: Where are you doing the selective replacement?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought that where it said `// do something`, you were going to tweak if necessary and fill in the blanks. :) I added some code and a live Java demo. Can you let me know if this is what you wanted? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the newline character that is not matched by `.*`. To change this default behavior of `.` you must use the singleline mode that you can set with `(?s)`. Example:

```
(?s)(\\[[^]]*\\])Gar_1\\b(.*?)\\1noGar\\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i really understood the question,you should give more information about it, but if you want to identify what is before noGar and Gar_1 you can use a lookahead.

```
\[.*\](?=(Gar_1|noGar))
```

It should give you 2 matches.

[rotura de lunas]